# Full width bars in Chart.js version 2.7.2

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

I am using Chart.js version 2.7.2 to create a simple, single series bar chart. I want every bar in the chart to fill all available space such that each bar in the chart "touches" its neighbor(s).

My research has indicated that I should be using the `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` settings, setting both to 1. I've done this and it makes the bars very wide, but it leaves a single pixel gap between them.

My initial assumption is that this was due to a grid line, but even if I turn off grid lines (`gridLines.display: false`) it still has the one-pixel gap.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4pvk0zo/2/)

Here is a screenshot. See the gap between each bar? How do I get rid of that?

[image: Chart.js bar char with a one-pixel gap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update to 2.8+ version of the library.

There were multiple instances of issues around this on their GitHub (i.e. [[BUG] Spacing between vertical bars with percentages set to 1](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3964) and [[BUG] Small gap between bars even with barPercentage and categoryPercentage set to 1](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5706)).

There was a [PR that made it into their 2.8.0 version](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5880) that is supposed to fix the issues around this (as noted by [@benmccann at the bottom of the PR page](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5880#issuecomment-477409997)).

Comment: Thanks! I upgraded to 2.8.0 and there is still a very faint line between the bars. Do you know what's going on here at this Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7rxbpmfz/1/